Use Puppeteer with real android device over USB
Is it possible to use Puppeteer with real android devices?
I can't see a way to connect to a USB device.
Would love to run tests on a physical handsets to test performance.
I can't see a way to connect via USB with the Puppeteer.connect() method.

No, Puppeteer doesn't automate Android.

Configuring remote debugging as described here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging with port forwarding should allow you to connect using browserURL in puppeteer.connect()
